# Qt default button on mac

Tags: qt, macos, defaultbutton

Mac have a capability to specify two default buttons, one activated by return and other by spacebar. One clear example is when you press power button on mac. It gives you a dialog box with quiet a few buttons, in which it shutdown is default for return key and restart is default for spacebar key. Is it possible to achieve such effect in Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Use `QPushButton`. On the "default" button use `setDefault` and `setAutoDefault()` to make them appear as a default button.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qpushbutton.html#default-prop

To handle the escape key (and possibly even the return key), you must set the shortcuts for each button to associate them with a corresponding key. It's easy to do that using Qt Creator/Designer.

Comment: I guess this is what I was looking for, but there 2 problems. If I'm using a buttonBox how would I change the property of Individual button and How can I achieve this in message-box?

Comment: You can use the `buttons()` method to get a list of buttons in that buttonBox. That will return a list of QPushButtons that you can modify as needed.